# How to create grouped dropdown list in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to create a grouped dropdown list in django admin.I could generate a normal drop downlist using "choices = ()".But I need something like this.

```
--Tools--
   Dotnet
   Vstudio
-- App --
  WMP
  Encoder
-- ABC --
   a
   b
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This format of choices tuple will do what you need:

```
items=(
    ("Animals", (("1","Monkey"), ("2","Turtle"))),
    ("Aliens", (("3","Zim"), ("4","Tak"))),
)

select=forms.ChoiceField(label="Selection", choices=items)
```

[image]